# Erro no envio - Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Configurei o meu nodemailer da seguinte maneira

```
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        port: 465,
        host: 'host do cpanel',
        auth: {
            user: 'email@dominio.com.br',
            pass: 'minhaSenha'
        }
    });
```

e ele da um erro

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

quando eu tento enviar o email, eu peguei os dados do host e a porta no proprio site do meu cpanel, o que acontece?

Comment: O que tens no `host`? é o endereço de smtp do servidor certo? consegues fazer um ping a esse endereço na consola?

Comment: o host é o que aparece no cpanel, como faz esse ping?

Comment: Na linha de comandos, por exemplo `ping smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: fiz e aparece isso 4 vezes Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.

Comment: Então tens algo a bloquear o teu acesso à internet... se `ping smtp.gmail.com` não funciona tens de ver a firewall ou as configurações de rede

Comment: o ping stmp.gmail.com funciona, apareceu aquilo quando eu fiz o ping no meu host do cpanel

Comment: Ah, então acho que tens de contatar o teu host. Talvêz seja possivel com um IP em vês de DNS?

Comment: coloquei o IP e o resultado foi o mesmo